# Equivalence classes "mod" a function

Tags: soft-question, terminology

Suppose I have a function, and I want to talk about the sets of points in the domain of the function that map to the same point in the image under the function. In general, what's a good term for this? Specifically, I have a hash function, and I want to talk about the equivalence classes "mod" the hash function, in a CS context. I know quotient spaces are relevant here, but that is specific to abstract algebra, and I want a term or expression that would be universally understood.

Comment: "inverse image" will be universally understood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a function $f : X \to Y$ the terminology is

- for a subset $B$ of $Y$, $f^{-1}(B) = \{x \in X : f(x) \in B\}$ is the **preimage** or **inverse image of $\pmb B$**
- for a singleton set $\{y\}$ the preimage $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ is also denoted $f^{-1}(y)$ and is also called the **fibre above $\pmb y$** or the **level set of $\pmb y$**. In American English "fiber" is the more common spelling.

I believe "fibre" is more common for discrete objects such as groups and vector spaces and "level set" for real-valued functions.

Answer (score 2):

What you describe is just the ordinary inverse image $f^{-1}$. For instance, if $f(x) = x^2$ and $x$ is real then $f^{-1}(y) = \{\pm \sqrt{y}\}$. You don't need equivalence classes or quotients.

In general, if $A$ and $B$ are sets and $f: A \rightarrow B$ is a function between them, there is always a function $f: P(A) \rightarrow P(B)$ defined by $f(U) = \{f(x) \ | \ x \in U\}$ for any $U \in P(A)$. Similarly there is an inverse image $f^{-1}: P(B) \rightarrow P(A)$ defined by $f^{-1}(V) = \{x \in A \ | \ f(x) \in V \}$ for any $V \in P(B)$.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the other answers (preimage or inverse image), but in the context of hash functions in computer science you could use the term [collision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_(computer_science)).
For instance, quoting this other [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_resistance):

> Collision resistance is a property of cryptographic hash functions: a
>   hash function is *collision resistant* if it is hard to find two
>   inputs that hash to the same output;